# php oop classes not playing nice with eachother

Tags: php, oop

Problem: I have 2 classes, DB class and a User class, that will work if placed in the same class but when i seperate them i cant figure out how to get the user class to connect using the DB class.

I have 'DBinterface' class and a 'user' class.

***dbinterface.php

```
<? class dbinterface {
    var $dbHost,
        $dbUser,
        $dbName,
        $dbPass,
        $dbUserTable;


    function User() {
        $this->dbHost = 'host':
        $this->dbUser = 'user';
        $this->dbName = 'name';
        $this->dbPass = 'pass';
        $this->dbUserTable = 'table';
    }

} // End dbinterface class definition ?>
```

***user.php

```
<?
include('dbinterface.php');
    class User {

        var $userID,
            $userName,
            $userPassword;

        function registerUser($userName, $userPassword) {
            // Connect to database
            $dbLink = mysql_connect($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass);
            if(!$dbLink) die("Could not connect to database. " . mysql_error());

            // Select database
            mysql_select_db($this->dbName);

            // Insert data
            $query = "insert into $this->dbUserTable values (NULL, \"$userName\", \"$userPassword\")";
            $result = mysql_query($query);

            // Test to make sure query worked
            if(!$result) die("Query didn't work. " . mysql_error());

            // Get the user ID
            $this->userID = mysql_insert_id();

            // Close database connection
            mysql_close($dbLink);

            // Assign the values to the data members
            $this->userName = $userName;
            $this->userPassword = $userPassword;
        } // End registerUser() ?>
```

PS:I have removed security and other mumbojumbo for easy legibility.
 *any and all help is MUCH appriciated!*

Comment: You can't just "separate" classes and hope that things still work the same. Your User class is referencing stuff that's now in a completely different class, of course it won't work. You'll need to actually think how you want to structure your classes...

Comment: thanks for the optimism but unfortunately i am new to PHP and still learning.

Comment: @user1082764 This has very little todo with php and more with your OO design and implementation. I would recommend learning the fundamentals of OOP before attempting to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well. I'll try to imagine what are you wanted to do :)
You need one class where you will store db variables, such as username, password and so on and 2nd class which will work with db-class params.

/* file1 */

```
Class db {

    private $_dbLink;
    private $_dbHost = 'host';
    private $_dbUser = 'user';
    private $_dbName = 'name';
    private $_dbPass = 'pass';
    private $_dbUserTable = 'table';

    public function connect ()
    {
        $this->_dbLink = mysql_connect($this->_dbHost, $this->_dbUser, $this->_dbPass);
        if(!$this->_dbLink) 
            throw new Exception ("Could not connect to database. " . mysql_error());
    }

    public function getLink()
    {
        return $this->_dbLink;
    }

    public function getUserName ()
    {
        return $this->dbUser;
    }

    public function getUserPass ()
    {
        return $this->_dbPass;
    }

    /* create the same methods for each variable */
}
```

/* file2 */

```
Class User {

    public function registerUser (/* params */)
    {
        $db = new db();
        $db->connect();

        /* your code */
        // Select database
        mysql_select_db($db->getDb(), $db->getLink());

        // Insert data
        $query = "insert into ".$db->getTable()." values (NULL, \"$userName\", \"$userPassword\")"; /* here is SQL-injection */
        $result = mysql_query($query, $db->getLink());
        /* and so on ...... */
    }
}
```

/* file3 */

```
// include file1
// include file2
$user = new User;
$user->registerUser(/* params */);
```

This is fast solution. You should learn how to create classes and project architecture. Use [php.net](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) for more information. Read about Object-oriented programming. And read about SQL-injections for safer code.

Answer (score 0):

$this inside User class will access only variables or objects and functions inside the 'Class User', you can not access variables or objects inside 'class dbinterface' to access that you have extend that class to your User class. You can try like this

```
class User extends dbinterface {

}
```

That will give you results.